# Why is $\Re(e^{(\lambda e^{i\theta}-\lambda)})\neq e^{(\lambda(\Re (e^{i\theta}-1)))}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Why is $\Re(e^{(\lambda e^{i\theta}-\lambda)})\neq e^{(\lambda(\Re (e^{i\theta}-1)))}$ ?

I always thought, that $\Re$ is linear, but if I compute LHS;

$\Re(e^{(\lambda e^{i\theta}-\lambda)})=\Re(e^{\lambda(e^{i\theta-1})})=\Re(e^{\lambda(\cos\theta-1)}e^{i\lambda\sin\theta})$

$=e^{\lambda(\cos\theta-1)}\Re(e^{i\lambda\sin\theta})=e^{\lambda(\cos\theta-1)}\cos(\lambda\sin\theta)$

but RHS gives only $e^{\lambda(\cos\theta-1)}$

where does it fail ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Linear doesn't mean you can move it past exponentiation. The real part is $\mathbb{R}$-linear indeed.

Comment: Multiplication by $2$ is also linear, but $2e^x\neq e^{2x}$.

Comment: OK, there is no faster way then. Thanks.